# SharePoint App deploy increments Web Apps URL

Tags: url, sharepoint

I've gained a bit of experience with SharePoint these days, but this is my first App attempt.  I have the app installed successfully in my Site Collection via VS2013.

But every time I make a change and either deploy from the context menu of the project or Start the solution with the app project as the start up a new web app is installed which increments the web app url hex.

[image]
this will become http://omg-bb5c1222e7d4d7.apps with the next deploy.

This is a problem because of the development configuration.  I have a VM running as my dev SharePoint server which is on its own domain.  Therefore the hosted address isn't in the corporate dns and thus the name doesn't resolve through proxy.  So to get the addressing to work I have the address in my local host file mapped to the ip address of the SP VM server and I also have an exception listed in firefox connection settings.

This works but not for very long as I need to deploy regularly at this early stage of development
[image]
but the connection exceptions for no proxy needs changing every deploy which is very annoying and time consuming.
[image]

Is there a way of making it deploy as the same url each deploy or is this a fundamental part of the app model?

Comment: I have the same question. Were you ever able to figure out what was going on?

Comment: I think sadly I just put up with it and changed it each deploy.  It wasn't worth spending any more time trying to find a fix. :-( Sorry.